# Jersey to filter and return a subset of representation list

Tags: java, jersey, filtering

Using Jersey 2.16, I'm looking to return a subset of a list by passing a boolean query parameter that will match a boolean field in a representation list.

For example, let's say I've got an apple resource like so:

```
@GET
@Path("apple/list")
public Response getAppleList(@DefaultValue("false") @QueryParam("isGreen") final boolean isGreen) {
    return appleService.getAppleList();
}
```

And my apple representation looks like this:

```
public class AppleRepresentation {

    private int id;
    private String colour;
    private String country;
    private String isGreen;
}
```

Is there a built-in Jersey filtering mechanism that will filter my `List<AppleRepresentation>` and return only green apples?

So far I've looked into [Jersey entity filtering](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html). From what I've seen there are ways to either filter out an entire list or fields with `SelectableEntityFilteringFeature`.

Unfortunately, I can't see an easy way to return only a subset of a list where a field = value.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the native stream filtering method of Java 8?

```
appleService.getAppleList().stream().filter(a -> a.isGreen);
```

Considering isGreen is a boolean…

(Didn't test it, though)

Comment: Haven't tried that. The project is not Java8 compatible though so unfortunately that's not an option. It seems like I'd have to add in another service method with a separate SQL query to get only the green apples. I was just wondering if there was jersey shortcut I could take for this.

Comment: Ah okay. Well if you can filter it on the database side, that's even better!